# What does "(" mean in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

Whenever I type an `(`, i.e ,an *opening parenthesis* in the **command Prompt**, this happens:

```
(
More?
```

If I continue typing `(` **or** **any other character**, it prompts me with the same message. **This is stopped**, if I enter `)`, i.e, the *closing parenthesis*, although I do get an error, which says :

```
) was unexpected at this time
```

Other than that, I **couldn't find what this command does**. Any ideas what it does ?

Comment: Parenthesis can be used to split commands across multiple lines, but maybe someone else can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: @User552853  Not really. When "more" appears, it's more related to(and perhaps only related to),there's an incomplete command.  Parens won't help here for example - you can't do for example dir(<new line>)/p   So parenthesis aren't helping to split a command across multiple lines there.  In fact caret is used to split  whatever command ,  across multiple lines. Try `echo ^` and it will say "More?". The round brackets would interfere with the command(unless the command uses them anyway).

Comment: ironically, if you put the ( in quotes like your question's title  suggests, then you won't get 'More. And the ( would be treated as literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

() isn't really a command but a grouping operator that allows you to group a sequence of commands together to use it in place where the CMD shell normally expects a single command to appear.
The commands between the () are actually executed in a separate instance of CMD. When you type "(" manually you enter that new instance and it waits for your commands.

```
if not exist c:\myfile (
  echo File doesn't exist
) else (
  echo File DOES exists
  del c:\myfile
)
```

Note that normally IF ELSE should be on the same line and you can only run a single command in the THEN and the ELSE clause.
Using the "()"  treats the entire (xxxxx) block as a single command and even as if it appeared in the same line.

Comment: i'd agree `()` is used for grouping commands, but perhaps not just that.  What about `for %f in (*.txt) do echo %f`   The parens aren't there to group commands, and if you remove the parens from there then you get a syntax error.

Comment: _The commands between the () are actually executed in a separate instance of CMD_? Truly? Check in Task Manager…

Comment: @barlop The () in FOR IN () are part of the syntax of FOR itself. If you follow that up with DO () the parenthesis that go with DO are again grouping parenthesis.

Comment: @JosefZ Logical instance with separate scope for e.g. setlocal. It is not a new process.

Comment: @Tonny what do you mean "logical instance"?  what'd it look like if it wasn't a new "logical instance"?  Can you point to anything on google that mentions this thing that you mention about ( creating a new "logical instance"?

Comment: @barlop I have read this somewhere (several times), but I'm not able to find any references at this time. If I recall correctly the processing of a (xxx) block is in essence similar to the CALL :label construct.

Comment: @Tonny What i've read is (something along the lines of), that pipes create a new instance of cmd (though as of yet, I can't demonstrate it and I don't quite know what that's all about).. but what I read several times, is re pipes anyway, rather than a (..) grouping of commands.

Comment: I found it  - this command demonstrates how a pipe creates(or at least can create), two processes   `pause>nul|set /p=sdf`  So if you open one cmd prompt, then you get one instance of cmd, and if you run that, then you end up with 3 instances.  The two new instances, one is for pause>nul and the other is for set /p=sdf,   You see it if you open "process explorer" and include the "command line" column.  I don't know if anything similar happens with the grouping parens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55788/discussion-between-barlop-and-tonny).

Comment: though i've never heard of anything similar with grouping parens, so if you do run into it  / find this thing you've read of sometimes, then please post it here in comment.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

A lot of good information has already been posted here —
e.g., parentheses are [“a grouping operator
that allows you to group a sequence of commands together
to use it in place where the CMD shell normally expects a single command
to appear”](//superuser.com/q/1190719/354511#1190730) that [“are like a *begin block* and *end block*”](//superuser.com/q/1190719/354511#1190729) —
but some simple things have been overlooked:

#### 1. How not to get the “unexpected at this time” error

You can get something useful to happen
simply by typing command(s) at the `More?`  prompt:

```
C:\> (
More? date /t
More? )
Tue 04/11/2017

C:\> (
More? dir \Windows\win.ini
More? )
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is ▒▒▒▒-▒▒▒▒

 Directory of C:\Windows

08/13/2014  12:26 PM               435 win.ini
               1 File(s)            435 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  ▒▒▒,▒▒▒,▒▒▒,▒▒▒ bytes free

C:\>
```

You can type multiple commands on separate lines, and you can move the `)` up to the end of the last line:

```
C:\> (
More? date /t
More? time /t
More? )
Tue 04/11/2017
06:18 PM

C:\> (
More? date /t
More? time /t)
Tue 04/11/2017
06:18 PM

C:\>
```

#### 2. How do `(` and `)` affect the meaning of a command?

As others have pointed out, there are commands like

```
C:\> for %f in (\Windows\*.dll) do @echo %f
```

where the `(`…`)` are part of the syntax of the command itself
(`FOR`, in this case). 
If you remove the parentheses, you get a syntax error. 
I’m not talking about that.

As stated *ad nauseam*, parentheses *group* commands. 
Consider this command line:

```
echo cat & echo dog | findstr /n a
```

It means

1. Do `echo cat`,
   and then
2. Do `echo dog | findstr /n a`
   Since the word “dog” does not contain the letter “a”,
   this command will produce no output.

Accordingly, the output for the above is

```
C:\> echo cat & echo dog | findstr /n a
cat
```

Similarly,

```
C:\> echo cat & echo dog | findstr /n o
cat
1:dog
```

in which we get the additional `1:dog` output,
because “dog” *does* contain “o”,
and “dog” is the first (**1**st) line of input to the `findstr` command.

Now consider

```
(echo cat & echo dog) | findstr /n a
```

(same as the above, but with added parentheses), which means

1. Do `echo cat`,
   and then
   do `echo dog`, and
2. Take the output from the above and pipe it into `findstr /n a`

So,

```
C:\> (echo cat & echo dog) | findstr /n a
1:cat

C:\> (echo cat & echo dog) | findstr /n o
2:dog
```

because the output from the left side (#1) of the command line is

```
cat
dog
```

and “a” is found on line **1** of that text,
and “o” is found on line **2**. 
We no longer get an output line that says only `cat`
(without a line number)
because the `echo cat` is no longer a free-standing command,
but is part of the ***group*** that makes up the left side of the pipeline.

Here’s a simpler example of command grouping:

```
C:\Temp> echo cat & echo dog > animals
cat

C:\Temp> type animals
dog

C:\Temp> (echo cat & echo dog) > animals

C:\Temp> type animals
cat
dog
```

And, of course, as shown above and in the other answers,
you can add line breaks within the group:

```
C:\> (
More? echo cat
More? echo dog
More? ) | findstr /n a
1:cat
```

#### 3. Do parentheses create a new instance of CMD?

I don’t think so; not in any obvious, meaningful way:

```
C:\> (cd windows)

C:\Windows> set a=aardvark

C:\Windows> (set a=bat)

C:\Windows> echo %a%
bat
```

Note that the `cd` in parentheses
changes the working directory of the main CMD process,
and the `set` in parentheses
overrides the variable value that was set outside of parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

The ( and ) are like a `begin block` and `end block`.  Anything that you can put into a batch file (.bat) can be typed into the command line.

For example I can write a batch file with can put a block of statements into an `if`:

```
if "%1"=="" (
  echo Multiple
  echo Lines when no parameter
)
echo END
```

Now when I run the batch without parameters I get all the commands between the `(` and `)` to run.  When a first parameter is supplied the only out put is 'END'.

Now back to the command line:  I know of no tricks or techniques to actually use this by directly typing on the command line.  But it does however follow the same rules.  On command line if enter the following:

```
(echo "1" & echo "2")
```

The output is:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Your second example shows your first sentence to be wrong or inaccurate, as even if it were correct,  they're not just for begin block and end block with multiple lines.  You can do an IF on one line with parentheses too.

Comment: Also the reason why an open parens can sometimes let you start a new line, is not to do with opening or ending a block. For example it happens also with `for %f in (`  and    And the non-do part of the 'for' (to the extent that any typical programming terminology can be applied to it) isn't generally considered a block.

Comment: note- when I wrote "second example" I was referring to ((echo "1" & echo "2")  and btw there's no reason to put 1 and 2 in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the notes.  I totally agree in the second example that there is not need for the quotes.  I was attempting to point out that the same behavior operates on command line as inside a batch file.  BTW I would be very interested if someone can add a command line that must have the () to operate correctly.

Comment: milton, you wrote "I would be very interested if someone can add a command line that must have the () to operate correctly"   In response, this would be an example  `for %f in (*.*) do echo %f`    So, removing parens causes that command to not execute.